# Countdown Timer start in particular second and restart

Tags: javascript

```
<span id="time">30:25</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 30,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
</script>
```

**

> How can I start the countdown timer for 30:25 sec. Its now ticking
> from 30:00.I need to show this in a page where the timer will autorestart

**

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to make this a simple and working timer from any number is to first get your number from your element, split its contents, and count down from there

```html
<span id="time">30:25</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        var currentMin = parseInt(display.textContent.split(":")[0])
        var currentSec = parseInt(display.textContent.split(":")[1]) 
         
        if(currentSec === 0){
            currentMin -= 1
            currentSec = 59
        } else{
            currentSec -=1
            if(currentSec < 10){
                //bonus: added a 0 before the second if its below 10
                currentSec = "0" + currentSec
            }
        }

        display.textContent = currentMin + ":" + currentSec;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }

    }, 1000);
}
window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 30,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
</script>
```